# Xcode: Document-based app window is not loading during attempt to subclass NSWindowController

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I really haven't done much and i'm already stuck.

So far i've done:

- added  **NSWindowController** subclass (**MikesWindowController.h** & .m)
- removed **windowNibName** from **MikesDocument.m** (since i'm implementing my own 
  WindowController subclass.)

I tried:

- Tested if NSLog would come back at **init**, **windowControllerDidLoadNib**, **applicationDidFinishLaunching**. Only the NSLog at init printed.
- And, tested the **Main Menu** -> **File** -> **New** after after compiling my Document app.

Am I implementing this right?  Thanks. Any suggestions would be great! Under **MikesDocument.m**

```
-(void)makeWindowControllers{
    MikesController *controller = [[MikesWindowController alloc]init];
    [self addWindowController:controller];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

After much deliberation I found that answer. Woohoo. Enjoy future.

- removed **initWithWindow** from my NSWindowController subclass
- implemented **initWithWindowNibName** to my NSWindowController subclass so now anytime I initialize I *must* specify the window nibName.

Below I implemented **initWithWindowNibName** in my NSWindowController subclass heres what it looks like:

**MikesWindowController.m**

```
-(id) initWithWindowNibName:(NSString *)windowNibName{
    self = [super initWithWindowNibName:windowNibName];
    return self;
}
```

(Below) Back again to the main document I corrected the **makeWindowController** method  and instantiated my controller with  "**MikesDocument"** (for MikesDocument.xib)  and added it.

**MikesDocument.m**

```
-(void)makeWindowControllers{  
    MikesWindowController *controller = 
        // must tell controller which nib file to use. 
        [[MikesWindowController alloc]initWithWindowNibName:@"MikesDocument"];  
        [self addWindowController:controller]; 

   }
```

Success! Don't even bother calling init or implementing init as it returns an error at any time.